# DATEADD using a decimal - workarounds?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, dateadd

I'm trying to do something like below (I've simplified the problem, to try and solve this individual part).

```
PRINT DATEADD(week, 0.2,  GETDATE())
```

Which I realise will not work due to the number parameter of dateadd is truncated to an int.

I'm trying to come up with a way of converting 0.2 to a number of hours and then being able to use something like (I'm ok with it being as accurate to the hour).

```
PRINT DATEADD(hour, X,  GETDATE())
```

Any ideas how to get started? I'm finding it tricky to find anything to get a decimal representation of one datepart in another datepart.

It's got to be a set based query for performance.

In theory I've got to make it so decimal years can be used as well, but I'll come to that as a seperate problem...

Comment: What does `0.2` of a week even mean?

Comment: Hi @Oded good point, I suppose 0.5 of a day would be a better example, where I need to add 12 hours. My problem domain is that I need to add 10% of a defined two part criteria to a date. e.g. 10% of 1 day, or 10% of 1 year or even 10% of 3 weeks. Tricky huh?! It's starting to hurt my head!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 week = 7 days = 168 hours = 10080 minutes

0.2 weeks = 2016 minutes

`PRINT DATEADD(minute, 2016,  GETDATE())`

To get this to work for years, you could write a `User Defined Function` where you can input a decimal of years, and then this is multiplied for minutes, and run `DATEADD` using `minutes`

Comment: Interesting thanks Curt that simplifies it nicely for me - the problem I'm working on it's easy to get overwhealmed! So I suppose for my problem domain I'll need to pass in a number, it's type (e.g. days, months, years) and then convert that to hours... cool, that shouldn't be tricky... now let's see if I can cram that into my SQL :-)

Comment: This should work in principle, so +1. **BUT**, for years, watch out for leap years!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with incase it comes in useful for anyone. Curt helped me open my eyes to that my problem was infact not as complex as I first thought. I've marked Curt's answer as the solution, but here is some sample code. Notably the 10% wasn't in my original question but it demonstrates why I needed decimals.

```
DECLARE @DatePart int,
        @DateNumber int;

SET @DatePart = 1
SET @DateNumber = 1                         

PRINT
    DATEADD(
                hour,
                CEILING
                (           
                    CASE @DatePart
                        WHEN 1 THEN @DateNumber * 24.000000 --days
                        WHEN 2 THEN @DateNumber * 168.000000 --weeks
                        WHEN 3 THEN @DateNumber * 730.484398 --months
                        WHEN 4 THEN @DateNumber * 8765.81277 --years
                    END / 100.000000 * 10.000000
                ),
                GETDATE()
            )
```

Comment: Hi @Curt this is what I came up with, thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help :)